# How many eggs in a Mille Crêpes Cake?

Tags: eggs, dessert, measurements, crepe

I've looked through a few recipes for Mille Crêpes and see that many use double as many eggs in the batter compared with most plain crêpe recipes (6 eggs per cup of flour compared to 3).

I'm not a fan of eggy crêpes so I'm tempted to go with my usual proportions. Does anyone know from experience whether the cake version really requires the extra eggs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra eggs help to make a more cake like consistency. Other wise it's just a stack of crepes!

To remove the eggy taste, remove half of the egg yolks. They will still cook more or less the same, and will be the same eggyness of a three egg batch

Comment: I tried the above suggestion (i.e. I used 3 whole eggs plus 3 whites). Certainly the taste was not too eggy but neither was the consistency more cakey. I expect a small amount of baking powder would have made a difference to the texture. With layers of ganache, sliced fruit and vanilla cream it tasted pretty damn good anyhow :)

Comment: @Chris Steinbach How did it compare to a 6 egg batch? A crepe is a VERY soft texture, and tend to colapse over a short time. The extra egg white binding makes it firmer (more cakey), I am not sure how more raising agent (BP) would improve this?

Comment: I see now, yes the crêpes were firm which worked well in the cake. The word cake, for me, brings to mind sponge cake and that coloured my expectations regarding texture. With that misunderstanding resolved I accept this as the answer.